# Built-in keyboard/touchpad and usb keyboard/mouse don't work after updating ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, touchpad, 17.04

I have a problem on Asus K54H. Built-in keyboard/touchpad and usb keyboard/mouse don't work after updating ubuntu from 16.04 to 17.04.

I cannot enter my pasword or do any other actions on lock screen.
But in bois and on anther OSs such as Windows and second Ubuntu 16.04 all keyboards and mouses are working correctly without any problems.

Could you help me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a USB mouse and keyboard the first & easiest thing you could try is logging in and going to `Settings>Keyboard` and make sure your layout is setup correctly / detected in some way.

Option 2 - if above doesn't work.

Hold `Shift` when the laptop is booting at the BIOS screen, if your built in keyboard works use it (or USB keyboard) to select the recovery menu option.

Recovery > Root option

`mount / -o remount rw`

`dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and select your keyboard

`exit` to boot into the desktop.

If none of the above fixes it, post an update for more complex troubleshooting steps.